# How do I set Excel row heights in R using a constant unit (e.g., inches)?

Tags: r, xlconnect, openxlsx

Background: I've written R code to create data summary tables that are exported into Excel templates using openxlsx. The tables vary in size and content with each new dataset, often spanning many pages. The data rows are all the same height, but each page also has a footnote at the bottom, which can vary in height. I have openxlsx code to adjust the height of the footnote row, which must be large enough to fit the text but small enough so the row doesn't get pushed onto the next page. The code is proprietary and I can't post it, but here's an example*:

```
setRowHeights(
  wb,
  sheet=excel.tab,
  rows=c(rowlist$lastrow.excel),
  heights=footnote.height2
)
```

*All of the inputs other than "wb" are dynamically assigned elsewhere in the program.

Problem: As far as I can tell, openxlsx only allows you to specify row heights in Excel row height units, as opposed to a standard measurement like inches. This seems to result in wildly different row heights (both in inches and in terms of fitting on the same exact page template) depending on the specific computer monitor I'm working on. For example, code that works fine when my laptop is hooked up to my work station will produce giant rows when I'm working on the laptop's monitor. I previously ran into the same issue with the XLConnect package, which makes me think this is a general issue with how R interacts with Excel as opposed to a unique limitation of openxlsx.

I noticed that other openxlsx functions allow you to input the screen's DPI (including vertical and horizontal DPI in some cases) for scaling, which led me to conclude that differences in DPI might account for the scaling discrepancies across screens. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to import the DPI of a specific screen into R in order to adjust the setRowHeights input to work with that screen.

I've spent countless hours researching and troubleshooting this problem with no luck. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The heights in `setRowHeights` are in points (as in font size point values). The conversion is about 72 points/inch. So the setting is apparently an absolute value, but the display must vary between screens based on resolution and zooming and perhaps other factors.

Comment: Huh, that makes this issue even stranger. Any idea how to adjust for those differences across screens? It sounds like the height unit isn't the issue at least, which is good to know!